# Access data in python3 associative arrays

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, associative

I'd like how to create and print associative arrays in python3... like in bash I do:

```
declare -A array
array["alfa",1]="text1"
array["beta",1]="text2"
array["alfa",2]="text3"
array["beta",2]="text4"
```

In bash I can do `echo "${array["beta",1]}"` to access data to print "text2".

How can I define a similar array in python3 and how to access to data in a similar way? I tried some approaches, but none worked.

Stuff like this:

```
array = ()
array[1].append({
            'alfa': "text1",
            'beta': "text2",
        })
```

But I can't access to data with `print(array['beta', 1])`. It is not printing "text2" :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you want a dictionary with compound keys:

```
adict = {
    ("alfa", 1): "text1",
    ("beta", 1): "text2",
    ("alfa", 2): "text3",
    ("beta", 2): "text4"
}

print(adict[("beta", 1)])
```

Answer (score 1):

This code is wrong, it gives an error:

```
array = ()
array[1].append({
        'alfa': "text1",
        'beta': "text2",
})
```

One way to achieve what you are looking for is with this code, using a list:

```
lst = []
lst.append({'alfa': "text1"})
lst.append({'beta': "text2"})
print(lst[1]['beta'])
```

Printed output:

```
text2
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
arry = []

arry.append({"alpha":"text1",
                 "beta": "text2"})
arry.append({"alpha":"text3",
                 "beta": "text4"})

for i,_ in enumerate(arry):
    print(arry[i]["alpha"])
    print(arry[i]["beta"])
```

#or

```
for i,element in enumerate(arry):
    print(element["alpha"])
    print(element["beta"])
```